# Spring framework child object in object gets lost after clicking on the website

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I started to learn spring some weeks ago and it’s going pretty nice so far. But there’s some nasty workaround that bothers me since some days. 
In short: I retrieve an object (from one database table *library*) with a child object which is a list (coming from another table *book*). The library and list of books is loaded correctly when it is called - my  Library class looks like this.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Library implements Serializable {

…

@OneToMany(mappedBy = „library“)
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Book> books;

…

}
```

I created a website with html and thymeleaf to show all the data in a html form. 
Somewhere inside the form I've put a select control, as shown here:

```
<select id="selectReader" name="selectReader" th:object="${bookstore.selectedReader}" th:field="*{id}" class="form-control form-control-sm" required="true" onchange="submit()">
  <option th:value="-1">Add Reader</option>
  <option th:each="item : ${readers}" th:value="${item.id}" th:text="${item.name}"/>
</select>
```

But, when I click the select control the page is reloaded and the list of books is gone.

```
@PostMapping("/updateBookstore/{id}")
public String updateBookstore(@PathVariable int id, @ModelAttribute Bookstore bookstore, Model model) {
  // bookstore.books is null
  // also checking the model for the attribute "bookstore.books" is null
}
```

My current workaround is to store my library object in a private field of the RestController, then the list of books is still there. But that seems like bad practice to me.

How can I setup the code so that the library is always loaded with the list of books without this workaround? Please tell me if you have an idea.

Comment: You need to show the controller method which loads the HTML form.
There is a `onchange="submit()"` on the select due to which it is getting posted to server and the page reloads.

Comment: Thank you @MohamedSanaulla. By now I can tell that it must be a problem with thymeleaf within the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to create a reference for thymeleaf in the HTML. By adding it I can see the list of books in the code.

```
<tr th:each="book, stat : *{books}">
  <td>Borrowed by</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" th:field="*{books[__${stat.index}__].borrowedBy}"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```